# How to add custom password encoder to Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm attempting to convert a web project to Spring.
I have already incorporated Spring Security, however the old project used SHA-1 converted to a  hex string to encrypt user passwords.

I was wondering how I can go about making a custom password encoder that will allow me to specify exactly how I want the password encrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you probably don't need a custom encoder, since it's quite easy using Security's namespace configuration [`<password-encoder>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-password-encoder):

```
<password-encoder hash="sha" base64="true" />
```

Put this line into your security-context.xml and it'll use [`ShaPasswordEncoder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/ShaPasswordEncoder.html) with SHA-1 algorithm and BASE64 encoding enabled.

Comment: Thanks. In my authentication-manager tag I have `<security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>`. And I have the bean `<bean class="org.springframework.security.providers.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>`. But I keep getting an error saying it can't find `org.springframework.security.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder`

Comment: What version of Spring Security do you use?

Comment: It's `org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder` in 3.1.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly use this.
Constructor argument is strength of SHA Encoder

```
<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="1" />
</beans:bean>
```